# Android Studio says I don't have Android Support Repository, but I do

Tags: android-studio

I updated Android Studio from 0.2 to 0.2.7 and now I can't use it. When I click on "New Project", click few times next, then finish, I get this error:

[image]

so I installed it through SDK manager, but I still keep getting that message! How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The SDK you used to download the `Android Support Repository` is external (`F:\Android\sdk`).

By default Android Studio uses it's own internal SDK, located in the `\sdk` sub-folder of the folder where Android Studio is installed.

In order to use your external SDK you have to configure Android Studio to use it.

Go to `File` -> `Other Settings` -> `Default Project Structure`.
Now add your required platform to the `Platform Settings` -> `SDK` section, **making sure to use your exernal SDK's path** (`F:\Android\sdk`).
Then set the default Project SDK to the added platform under `Project Settings` -> `Project`.

**Edit:**
If you want to use the bundled SDK manager, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18685328/1326821) for a solution.