# Android Studio Error: "You must install the Android Support Repository though the SDK Manager"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I just initialised a project on Android Studio, and it was working fine in version 0.2.6, but in 0.2.7, I get this error:

[image]

It creates a folder inside my Applications directory, but it does not initialize the project. Any help regarding this problem would be appreciated. I get no problems with version 0.1.1 through version 0.2.6, but when it comes to 0.2.7, things start to get problematic, like this and I can't even start a project.

Comment: Have you tried starting AS the Administrator?

Comment: just install ASR via SDK Manager.

Comment: @Jon Yes, I have. Same thing happens.

Comment: @Leonidos How do I do that. A full answer would be appreciated.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Did you try looking through the list of available packages in the SDK Manager?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With 2.7 update I got the same issue. It looks like now Android Studio thinks `sdk` lays in under its own folder at `android-studio/sdk`.

You should be able to use `android` app under `android-studio/sdk/tools` to get missing components (not tested).

Another solution would be to fix `sdk` path (tested):

Close any projects then drop to `Welcome to Android Studio Dialog`

1. Select Configure -> Project Defaults -> Project Structure
2. Select SDKs -> Android SDK -> Android SDK Home Path
3. Update it to your previous sdk location.

Comment: I did your 'fix sdk path' solution, and that solves this.  Thanks!

Comment: No, it solved it for the first new project I created, but now it's broken again...it won't work for the next new project, even tho the new path is still in place.

Answer (score 3):

You must manually run SDK Manager.

Folder: `android-studio/sdk/tools`

Search for `android` or `android-sdk`

The new Support Repository must be already selected, and you need only click the "Install" button.

Answer (score 3):

got the same problem when applying the last patch (2.7). I've resolved it by copying SDK Manager.exe from android-studio\sdk\tools\lib to android-studio\sdk\ then I've launched it and install the missing component.

After restarting Android Studio it works again !

Answer (score 2):

Just as Leonidos said, install ASR through SDK Manager:

Tools > Android > SDK Manager ; Navigate to the Extras folder, and select Android Support Repositories.

Click install packages and it will work fine

Answer (score 1):

I did a fresh install of Java, SDK and Android Studio, update it to  0.2.7 and install the ASR through SDK Manager, but the messages comes again.

So i found this solution.

The most common problem for Android Studio and 64Bit Windows System is the **no 8.3 short path** for 
**C:\Program Files** and **C:\Program Files (x86)**.

```
find_java.exe
```

couldn't handle it and give a wrong path back.

Finally do this:

```
dir /x C:
```

-- It shows no 8.3 short paths.

```
 fsutil 8dot3name query C:
```

-- It shows NtfsDisable8dot3NameCreation is 1 on "C:", 
    means 8.3 short path won't be created in "C:".

Then I enable the generation of 8.3 short name by:

```
fsutil 8dot3name set C: 0
```

and create short names for **C:\Program Files** and **C:\Program Files (x86)** in windows recovery mode by:

```
fsutil file setshortname "C:\Program Files" PROGRA~1

fsutil file setshortname "C:\Program Files (x86)" PROGRA~2
```

And now `dir /x C:` can show the short names.

And now `find_java.exe -s`

can show the short path `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_2\bin\java.exe`.

And now `find_java.bat` and `android.bat` can work good now!

[source](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28196#c46)

Also copying SDK Manager.exe from android-studio\sdk\tools\lib to android-studio\sdk\

Comment: Much easier to simply install everything under C:\ and get rid of paths with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few ideas to try that should hopefully help. These can be found by using `Ctrl + Shift + A`.

"*Sync project with Gradle*" - (it's also often in the toolbar with a green and yellow ball and a blue down arrow next to three android icons)

"*Gradle*" and select the ToolBox option; then hit the blue refresh icon to refresh all the gradle projects

"*Project Structure...*" (also available under File) Under the Libraries project settings you should see a valid reference to your support library. You'll also want to skim through everything to make sure everything else looks good with the project.

"*Invalidate Caches...*" (another available under File) Invalidate and restart. This one got me going again after the previous upgrade generated a bunch of errors.

Some of these may be redundant, but after having fought with similar issues in the past it's just a few easy things I've found to check.

If refreshing everything doesn't work you can always pull up the Android SDK from Tools -> Android -> SDK or from the toolbar with the blue/green boxy android that has a black down arrow. It should be next to the Sync Gradle button.

Answer (score 0):

I update the Android Studio(AS) and see the same issue.

However, there is something slightly different about what I find out.

I actually have two sdks because I shift from Eclipse to AS.

Hence, I get one sdk in

c:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk

and anther in

c:\Android\android-studio\sdk.

And the real one that I use is in c:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk.

The important thing is that, I find that only one of the sdk setting is changed after the update.

```
Quick Start > Configure > Project Defaults > Project Structure

> Platform Settings > SDKs


1.7
        JDK home path:

        C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_10

Android 2.2 Platform

        Android SDK home path:

        C:\Program Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk

Android 4.0.3 Platform

        same as 2.2

Android 4.2.2 Platform

        Android SDK home path:

        C:\Android\android-studio\sdk    <- it is modified after update!!!!

Android 4.3 Platform

        same as 2.2
```

After fixing the path in 4.2.2, I could create new project successfully again.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, if you install Android Studio in the same directory as the SDK, this error will pop up. Just install it somewhere else.
For instance, I had it installed at C:\Android\, along with the SDK. Then, I decided to install it at C:\Program Files (x86)\Android Studio and it simply worked.