# Android SDK issue when try to build existing project

Tags: android, android-sdk-manager

I'm new in Android development. I open existing project and get error:

```
Error:Could not find com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0.
Required by:
    project :app

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
```

When I open a link I see [image]

What do I need to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Error: "You must install the Android Support Repository though the SDK Manager"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681155/android-studio-error-you-must-install-the-android-support-repository-though-th)

Comment: Look under tab SDK Tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click on sdk tools and select  support repository click apply and let it download and install once completed. rebuild your project.Android support libs provide backward compatibility and support for newer feature such as recycle view, constraint layout and others.